# Cut string from the first to the last ocurrence of a given tag

Tags: java, string

Suppose that we have a string formatted like this:

```
"@tag some text goes here and @tag nobody @tag should care about it @tag"
```

I want to cut the string and get the exact same text from the first tag to the very last tag (excluding the tags).

Is there a method from the Java library which lets me do that or will I have to implement it myself? I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: check out `indexOf()`, `length()`, `substring()` from String

Comment: If `string.replaceAll()` would be a custom implementation, then yes you'd need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Oh, of course! I got it. I think I was missing the obvious here. I feel kind of ashame for having posted this... Too much stress I guess. Anyway, thank you! Feel free to make an answer anyway so I can mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it with the standard `String` methods, as follows:

- Locate the position of the first occurrence of `@tag` using `indexOf`
- Locate the position of the last occurrence of `@tag` using `lastIndexOf`
- Cut out the substring between the tags using `substring`
- Remove the tags themselves using `replaceAll`

Here is how you can code it:

```
String str = "@tag some text goes here and @tag nobody @tag should care about it @tag";
String tag = "@tag";
int start = str.indexOf(tag);
int end = str.lastIndexOf(tag);
if (start >= 0 && end > start) {
    String res = str
        .substring(start, end)
        .replaceAll(Pattern.quote(tag)+"\\s*", "")
        .trim();
    System.out.println("Result: '"+res+"'");
} else {
    System.out.println("Tag not found.");
}
```

Note the use of `Pattern.quote` - this is done for safety, in case your actual tags contain regex metacharacters.

Also note the `+"\\s*"` after the regex. It removes the space after the tag, if any.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/cFsEtg).

Comment: @devnull A question mark would work too, although I prefer treating the space after the tag as something trimmable. I added a call of `quote` in the assumption that `"@tag"` is *not* OP's *real* tag, in which case it might have some metacharacters. When I deal with regex, I prefer to be safe rather than sorry :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` plus length and `lastIndexOf` to help you out and `replaceAll` to get rid of tags in the middle.

```
    String s = "@tag some text goes here and @tag nobody @tag should care about it @tag";
    String searchString = "@tag";
    int begin = s.indexOf(searchString) + searchString.length();
    int end = s.lastIndexOf(searchString);
    String between = s.substring(begin, end);
    String withoutSearchString = between.replaceAll(searchString, "");
    System.out.println(withoutSearchString);
```

Comment: needs some math to remove len of tag

Comment: Just saw that. Added.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want the following.

You have your string

```
String string = "@tag some text goes here and @tag nobody @tag should care about it @tag";
```

Split it into array separated by @tag

```
String[] tags = string.split("@tag");
```

Loop through each array and get rid of first 4 characters (@tag)

```
for(int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    tags[i] = tags[i].substring(4);
```

Hope this helped. There are numerous ways you can do it if you read up on [String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: too much code for this. indexOf, lastIndexOf, remove len of tag and substring